# Replace multiple spaces, multiple occurrences of a comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to clean an input field client side.

Current Value

`string = 'word, another word,word,,,,,, another word, ,,;`

Desired Value after cleaning

`string = 'word,another word,word,another word;`

Simplified version of what I have tried http://jsfiddle.net/zg2e7/362/

Comment: Just to be clear: is this input possible: `, ,,;`? And if yes, how should it be handled?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```js
var str = 'word,word,word,,,,,new word, , another word';
document.body.innerHTML = str.replace(/(?:\s*,+)+\s*/g, ',');
```

1. You need to use `g` modifier to find and replace all instances
2. You need to also match optional whitespace between commas and on both sides of them.

Regex explanation:

- `(?:\s*,+)+` - 1 or more sequences of

  - `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace characters
  - `,+` - 1 or more commas.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

```js
string = 'word, another word,word,,,,,, another word, ,,';
console.log(string.replace(/(,)[,\s]+|(\s)\s+/g ,'$1').replace(/^,|,$/g,''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `split` and `trim` and `map` and `join` rather than regex being that regex can be a bit clunky.

```
$.map(str.split(','),function(item,i){
    if(item.trim()){
        return item.trim()
    } 
}).join(',')
```

So split the string by the `,` and then use the map function to combine them. If the item has value after being trimmed then keep the value. Then after it has been mapped to a array of the valid values join them with a comma.

Comment: The result is `word,word,word,new word,another word,`. The final comma is redundant, I guess.

Comment: Valid issue. I updated it to use the map function and the join function.